# Stuck in a for loop - no "next button"

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape all the teams that were entered in contests for a particular date on Rotogrinder/Resultdb. However, I just realized that when the contest that is being scraped have less than 50 entries ( only one page), my code stays stuck in the loop, because I use the next button to normally gets out of that loop. Here is my code:

*** I change three lines to go directly to a contest were the problem occurs.

```
#Packages:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


# Driver
chromedriver =("C:/Users/Michel/Desktop/python/package/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

# DF taht will be use later 
results = pd.DataFrame()
best_lineups=pd.DataFrame()
opti_lineups=pd.DataFrame()

#For loop over all DATES:

CALENDAR=[]
CALENDAR.append("2017-10-04")
CALENDAR.append("2017-10-05")



for d in CALENDAR:
    driver.get("https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb/date/"+d+"/sport/4/")
   
    time.sleep(10)
    
    
    
    try:
        
        contest= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]")
    
  

        contest.click()
        list_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        hlink=[]
        for ii in list_links:
            hlink.append(ii.get_attribute("href"))
        sub="https://rotogrinders.com/resultsdb"
        con= "contest"
        contest_list=[]
        for text in hlink:
            if sub in text:
                if con in text:
                    contest_list.append(text)
                    
# comment next two lines and replace by following three to get directly to where the code keep looping                   

#         for c in contest_list:
#             driver.get(c)
       
        c=contest_list[3:5]
        for a in c:
            
            driver.get(a)
   
        
            n=1
            while n<100:
  

                n+=1
                time.sleep(10)
        
#       
                try:    
                    Data=driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//tbody//tr//td//span//a[text() != ""]').is_displayed()
        
                    next_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")           
               
# Get tables to get the user names
                    tables=[]
                    tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
                    users_df  = tables[0][['Rank','User']]
                    users_df['User'] = users_df['User'].str.replace(' Member', '')
                    users_df['order of appearence'] = users_df.groupby('User')['User'].transform(lambda x : x.duplicated().cumsum().add(1))
            # Initialize results dataframe and iterate through users
      
                    for i, row in users_df.iterrows():
                        rank = row['Rank']
                        user = row['User']
                    
                        count_IP= users_df["order of appearence"][i]-1
                
                                        
    # Find the user name and click on the name
                        user_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[text()='%s']" %(user))[count_IP]
                        user_link.click()

    # Get the lineup table after clicking on the user name
                        tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
                        lineup = tables[1]

    # Restructure to put into resutls dataframe
                        lineup.loc[9, 'Name'] = lineup.iloc[9]['Salary']
                        lineup.loc[10, 'Name'] = lineup.iloc[9]['Pts']

                        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(lineup['Name'].values.reshape(-1, 11), 
                        columns=lineup['Pos'].iloc[:9].tolist() + ['Total_$', 'Total_Pts'] )
    
                        temp_df.insert(loc=0, column = 'User', value = user)
                        temp_df.insert(loc=0, column = 'Rank', value = rank)
                        temp_df["Date"]=d
                        results = results.append(temp_df)  
    
                    
                    next_button[2].click()    
                    results = results.reset_index(drop=True)
    
                except NoSuchElementException: 
                    break
    except NoSuchElementException: 
        pass      
        

driver.close()
```

I try to add the following at the end of the loop , but it did not work:

```
 try:
    next_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")
                        
    next_button[2].click()    
 except NoSuchElementException:
     break    ***( I also try with pass)
```

How could I solve that issue ?

Comment: Post a link please

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    next_button =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@type='button']")
    next_button[2].click()    
 except NoSuchElementException:
    n = 100
    break
```

Your page control variable is `n`, set it 100 and the while loop will stop.

Comment: It is not working. I am still stuck in the loop. I feel that the next_button can still be found and no NoSuchElementException is raised... and therefore do not go into the except part

Comment: Well, if it's found, on its 100th occurrence the loop will stop - the `while` will kick in, there are no 2 options there. Are you sure it's not a case of a slow runtime? Print the value of `n` at the cycle start, to see where in the repetitions you are.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the button is enabled using `webElement.isEnabled()` and `webElement.isDisplayed()`. Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943847/check-whether-element-is-clickable-in-selenium) about clickable elements.

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that the button is not clickable. My goal is to stop the loop, while the button is not clickable, because there is only one page. Otherwise, I am continually scrapping the same table...

Comment: Can't you check if it's clickable, and if not, stop the loop?

Comment: That is what @Todor proposed, but it is not working. It is like the button is not clickable, but there is no exception raised...