# Looping through different pages and scraping data on Javascript website

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping

I think I'm getting close but I can't figure out why my code isn't working as expected. I want to scrape the data from the first page, then click the `next` (arrow) button and move to the next page and do the same and so on until the `next` arrow button is greyed out, at which point the driver should quit. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code:

```html
   
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import *
import time
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import html5lib


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_driver_path = '/Users/Justin/Desktop/Python/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
url = "https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source

master_list = []

def get_next_page(url):
    while driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[9]') != True:
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[9]/a').click()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
        container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={
            'class': 'dataTables_scrollBody'})
        df = pd.read_html(str(container))
        dfs = df[0]
        page_next_data = dfs[['#', 'Name', 'Symbol', 'Max Supply', 'Summary', 'Price', 'Market Cap',
                              '24h Volume', '1h %', '24h %', '7d %', 'Circulation', 'Total Supply', 'Consensus Method']]
        return master_list.append(page_next_data)

    else:
        driver.quit()


def get_data(callback, url):
    global soup, container
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
    container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={
        'class': 'dataTables_scrollBody'})
    df = pd.read_html(str(container))
    dfs = df[0]
    page_one_data = dfs[['#', 'Name', 'Symbol', 'Max Supply', 'Summary', 'Price', 'Market Cap',
                        '24h Volume', '1h %', '24h %', '7d %', 'Circulation', 'Total Supply', 'Consensus Method']]
    return master_list.append(page_one_data)
    return callback(args)


print(get_data(get_next_page, url))
```

This is the result it's giving me from the first page but it doesn't continue to the next page nor it gives me any errors or anything.

```html
    #          Name Symbol  ...  Circulation Total Supply               Consensus Method
0   1       Bitcoin    BTC  ...     18713700     18713700                  Proof of Work
1   4  Binance Coin    BNB  ...    153432897    169432897                            NaN
2   5       Cardano    ADA  ...  31948309441  45000000000       Delegated Proof of Stake
3   7           XRP    XRP  ...  46135372183  99990461026  Federated Byzantine Agreement
4  10  Bitcoin Cash    BCH  ...     18742750     18742750                  Proof of Work
5  11      Litecoin    LTC  ...     66752415     66752415                  Proof of Work
6  12     ChainLink   LINK  ...    428009554   1000000000                  Proof of Work

[7 rows x 14 columns]
(pyfinance) Justins-MacBook-Pro:Python-for-Finance-Repo-master Justin$
```

Comment: You nicely outlined what you want this code to do.  However, we also need you to detail what it *is* doing, including a trace of the suspect values (use `print`s) and isolation of the problem (remove superfluous code).  See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I edited the post. It's returning the first page just fine but I can't get it to execute the callback function or even to throw an error so I know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you made it too complicated. You had two `return` statements in one function and also you used `args` variable which doesn't exist in the function scope. See adapted and working code below:

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import *
import time
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import html5lib

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
url = "https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
master_list = []

def get_next_page(url):
    proceed = True

    while driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[9]/a') != True and proceed:        
        try:
            driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[9]/a')[0].click()
        except Exception:
            proceed = False

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
        container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'dataTables_scrollBody'})
        df = pd.read_html(str(container))
        dfs = df[0]
        page_next_data = dfs[['#', 'Name', 'Symbol', 'Max Supply', 'Summary', 'Price', 'Market Cap', '24h Volume', '1h %', '24h %', '7d %', 'Circulation', 'Total Supply', 'Consensus Method']]
        master_list.append(page_next_data)
    else:
        driver.quit()

def get_data(callback, url):
    global soup, container
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
    container = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'dataTables_scrollBody'})
    df = pd.read_html(str(container))
    dfs = df[0]
    page_one_data = dfs[['#', 'Name', 'Symbol', 'Max Supply', 'Summary', 'Price', 'Market Cap', '24h Volume', '1h %', '24h %', '7d %', 'Circulation', 'Total Supply', 'Consensus Method']]
    master_list.append(page_one_data)
    
    return callback(url)

get_data(get_next_page, url)
print(master_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm teaching myself python and I couldn't figure out where to go from where I was. I don't understand "and proceed:" Is proceed a special variable in python that tells the program to continue to the next step if set to = True? Also seeing that Exception is capitalized and you haven't defined it is "except Exception" just a short way of saying "if you find an exception then stop iterating? Again thank you so much! This is very helpful.

Comment: `proceed` is just a variable name which you can change. The `try` and `except` is there just to find out when the next arrow button is not clickable anymore (greyed out). More appropriate way would be just to use webdriver method to test if this element is clickable like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943847/check-whether-element-is-clickable-in-selenium/26947299) Finally if you could quit the driver inside the `except` you would get en error when evaluating the `while` condition because the browser window would be already closed at that moment.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that, even now, you haven't tested any smaller pieces of your code.
Look at your logic:

```
while driver...
    driver....click()
    ...
    return master_list.append(...)
```

1. You exit the function on the first iteration.
2. Append is an in-place operation; it always returns `None`.

In short, you could skip the loop, skip the click and data extraction, and simply replace your entire function with the body

```
return None
```